# Prove that this series converges: ${(\frac{n}{n+1}})^{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to prove that this series converges: $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{({\frac{n}{n+1}})^{n^2}}$ ?

I tried root test, ratio test, comparison test, Cauchy condensation test, but none works. Any hints?

Comment: Does this remind you at all of the number $e$?  What part of it reminds you of $e$?  What extra is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using  [Root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) we get

$$\\ \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sqrt [ n ]{ { \left( \frac { n }{ n+1 }  \right)  }^{ { n }^{ 2 } } }  } =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { \left( \frac { n }{ n+1 }  \right)  }^{ n } } =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { \left( 1+\frac { -1 }{ n+1 }  \right)  }^{ -\left( n+1 \right) \frac { -n }{ n+1 }  } } =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { e }^{ \frac { -n }{ n+1 }  } } ={ e }^{ -1 }<1$$

Comment: You could also write $\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^{-n}$.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it might be instructive to present a way forward that uses the comparison test.  To that end, we proceed.

---

It is straightforward to show that $a_n=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$ is monotonically decreasing (See the note at the end of this post) and bounded below trivially by $0$.

Thus, $a_n$ converges.  Furthermore, for $n\ge 1$, $\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\le \frac12$.

Obviously then, can write

$$\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}\le \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n =1<\infty$.

> Therefore, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}$ converges by comparison to the geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$.

---

**NOTE:**

To show that $a_n=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$ is monotone decreasing, we form the ratio $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ and show that this ratio is greater than or equal to $1$.  We write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}&=\frac{\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n}{\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{n+1}}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}\,\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) \\\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}\,\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) \tag1\\\\
&\ge \left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)}\right)\,\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) \tag 2\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown.  In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we applied Bernoulli's Inequality.